# read array element from stdin with space delimited number in bash

Tags: arrays, bash, shell

I am trying this small piece of code in bash:

```
echo "Enter number(a b c)"
read natc
echo ${natc[1]}
```

The input should be 3 number in one line, space delimited, read from stdin, e.g. `4 5 6` 
and I would like to access them in array,`natc[]` i.e. `natc[0]=4, natc[1]=5` etc.

there are many example in google, but mostly reading the array from a file or predefined value. How can I achieve my goal?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can read into an array with `-a`:

```
read -a natc
```

Comment: Good one, and then you can access the records with `echo ${natc[0]}`, `echo ${natc[1]}`...

Answer (score 3):

Use `-p` and `-a` read options:

```
read -p "Enter an array: " -a natc
Enter an array: a b c d

echo "${natc[0]}"
a
echo "${natc[1]}"
b
echo "${natc[2]}"
c
echo "${natc[3]}"
d

echo "${#natc[@]}"
4
```